# How to run a function against several dataframes and output dataframes with the same name as input in R

Tags: r

I have several dataframes that I am applying a function to

The function works but I would like to lapply it to several dataframes and output the result according to the input names.

Here is an example of one of the dataframes

```
structure(list(chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("chr1", 
"chr10", "chr11", "chr12", "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", 
"chr17", "chr18", "chr19", "chr2", "chr20", "chr21", "chr22", 
"chr3", "chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chrX", 
"chrY"), class = "factor"), leftPos = c(100260254L, 100735342L, 
100805662L), strand.x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("-", 
"+"), class = "factor"), X50CellJ_SLX.9395.FSeqJ.fq.gz = c(7L, 
295L, 132L), Cytospongex10_SLX.9395.FSeqK.fq.gz = c(72L, 256L, 
148L), FFPE20X_SLX.9395.fq.gz = c(5L, 74L, 36L), Tumour10_SMACCO_AH_088_SLX.9396.FSeqH.fq.gz = c(13L, 
154L, 65L), Tumour11_SMACCO_SH_020_SLX.9396.FSeqI.fq.gz = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), Tumour12_SMACCO_ED_008_SLX.9396.FSeqJ.fq.gz = c(3L, 
25L, 8L), Tumour13_SMACCO_AH_086_SLX.9396.FSeqK.fq.gz = c(7L, 
120L, 28L), Tumour1_SMACCO_AH_100_SLX.9396.FSeqA.fq.gz = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), Tumour2_SMACCO_AH_058_SLX.9396.FSeqB.fq.gz = c(24L, 
98L, 42L), Tumour3_SMACCO_SH_051_SLX.9396.FSeqC.fq.gz = c(29L, 
92L, 29L), Tumour4_SMACCO_ED_031_SLX.9396.FSeqD.fq.gz = c(18L, 
53L, 14L), Tumour5_SMACCO_RS_027_SLX.9396.FSeqE.fq.gz = c(8L, 
93L, 17L), Tumour7_SMACCO_AH_026_SLX.9396.FSeqF.fq.gz = c(30L, 
205L, 60L), Tumour9_SMACCO_ST_024_SLX.9396.FSeqG.fq.gz = c(15L, 
129L, 17L), strand.y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("-", 
"+"), class = "factor"), Tumour14_SMACCO_AH_094_SLX.9394.FSeqA.fq.gz = c(0L, 
7L, 3L), Tumour15_SMACCO_WG_006_SLX.9394.FSeqB..fq.gz = c(3L, 
19L, 4L), Tumour16_SMACCO_ST_035_SLX.9394.FSeqC.fq.gz = c(1L, 
23L, 8L), Tumour17_SMACCO_ST_034_SLX.9394.fq.gz = c(7L, 26L, 
5L), Control19_SLX.9394.FSeqE.fq.gz = c(51L, 256L, 36L), Control20_SLX.9394.FSeqF.fq.gz = c(23L, 
110L, 34L), Control21_SLX.9394.FSeqG..fq.gz = c(30L, 56L, 
11L), Control22_SLX.9394.FSeqH.fq.gz = c(22L, 72L, 24L), Control23_SLX.9394.FSeqI.fq.gz = c(10L, 
23L, 2L), Control25_SLX.9394.FSeqJ.fq.gz = c(17L, 72L, 8L), 
    Control27_SLX.9394.FSeqK.fq.gz = c(10L, 21L, 9L), Control28_SLX.9395.FSeqA.fq.gz = c(13L, 
    40L, 4L), Control29_SLX.9395.FSeqB.fq.gz = c(14L, 39L, 
    6L), Control30_SLX.9395.FSeqC.fq.gz = c(5L, 32L, 5L), 
    Control31_SLX.9395.FSeqD.fq.gz = c(7L, 11L, 5L), Control32_SLX.9395.FSeqE.fq.gz = c(5L, 
    32L, 4L), Control33_SLX.9395.FSeqF.fq.gz = c(10L, 25L, 
    6L), Control34_SLX.9395.FSeqG.fq.gz = c(3L, 32L, 1L), 
    Control35_SLX.9395.FSeqH.fq.gz = c(10L, 33L, 0L), Controls = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Samples = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("chr", "leftPos", 
"strand.x", "X50CellJ_SLX.9395.FSeqJ.fq.gz", "Cytospongex10_SLX.9395.FSeqK.fq.gz", 
"FFPE20X_SLX.9395.fq.gz", "Tumour10_SMACCO_AH_088_SLX.9396.FSeqH.fq.gz", 
"Tumour11_SMACCO_SH_020_SLX.9396.FSeqI.fq.gz", "Tumour12_SMACCO_ED_008_SLX.9396.FSeqJ.fq.gz", 
"Tumour13_SMACCO_AH_086_SLX.9396.FSeqK.fq.gz", "Tumour1_SMACCO_AH_100_SLX.9396.FSeqA.fq.gz", 
"Tumour2_SMACCO_AH_058_SLX.9396.FSeqB.fq.gz", "Tumour3_SMACCO_SH_051_SLX.9396.FSeqC.fq.gz", 
"Tumour4_SMACCO_ED_031_SLX.9396.FSeqD.fq.gz", "Tumour5_SMACCO_RS_027_SLX.9396.FSeqE.fq.gz", 
"Tumour7_SMACCO_AH_026_SLX.9396.FSeqF.fq.gz", "Tumour9_SMACCO_ST_024_SLX.9396.FSeqG.fq.gz", 
"strand.y", "Tumour14_SMACCO_AH_094_SLX.9394.FSeqA.fq.gz", 
"Tumour15_SMACCO_WG_006_SLX.9394.FSeqB..fq.gz", "Tumour16_SMACCO_ST_035_SLX.9394.FSeqC.fq.gz", 
"Tumour17_SMACCO_ST_034_SLX.9394.fq.gz", "Control19_SLX.9394.FSeqE.fq.gz", 
"Control20_SLX.9394.FSeqF.fq.gz", "Control21_SLX.9394.FSeqG..fq.gz", 
"Control22_SLX.9394.FSeqH.fq.gz", "Control23_SLX.9394.FSeqI.fq.gz", 
"Control25_SLX.9394.FSeqJ.fq.gz", "Control27_SLX.9394.FSeqK.fq.gz", 
"Control28_SLX.9395.FSeqA.fq.gz", "Control29_SLX.9395.FSeqB.fq.gz", 
"Control30_SLX.9395.FSeqC.fq.gz", "Control31_SLX.9395.FSeqD.fq.gz", 
"Control32_SLX.9395.FSeqE.fq.gz", "Control33_SLX.9395.FSeqF.fq.gz", 
"Control34_SLX.9395.FSeqG.fq.gz", "Control35_SLX.9395.FSeqH.fq.gz", 
"Controls", "Samples"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is what I have so far

```
mylist <- list(A = OriginalMeta , B = SLX9392 , C = SLX9393, D = SLX9397, E = Gastric, F = Dysplasia, G = GoodDysplasia, H = Cholangio, I = LCM_PS14_1105_1F) 

sortIt <- function(df1) {

  df1$strand.x<- NULL
  df1$strand.y<- NULL
  df1$strand<-NULL
  df1$X.<-NULL
  names(df1)[1] <- c("chr")
  #Get rid of X and Y chromosomes
  df1 <- df1[!grepl("chrX", df1$chr), ]
  df1 <- df1[!grepl("chrY", df1$chr), ]
xyAss3<-df1
return(xyAss3)
}

lapply(names(mylist),
       sortIt(x)write.csv(mylist[x],
                            file =paste0(x,'.csv')))
```

The thing is I just dont know how to feed the mylist into the function. Should I call x in the lapply df1? I'm a bit confused as to how to tie it all together.

Comment: You've got your `sortIt` function returning an object that doesn't exist (`xyAss3`), and you're not using that function in your call to `lapply`. So I'm confused about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: My fault. I truncated the function because it is quite long. I've changed the code so it makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll do better to fold the creation of the .csv into your function and then use a `for` loop to apply that function to each object in your list in turn. So something like this, where `df` is the sample data frame you posted:

```
mylist <- list(A = df, B = df)

sortIt <- function(i) {

  df = mylist[[i]]
  df[,"strand.x"] <- NULL
  df[,"strand.y"] <- NULL
  df[,"strand"] <- NULL
  df[,"X."] <- NULL
  names(df) <- c("chr", names(df)[2:length(names(df))])
  df <- df[!grepl("chrX", df$chr), ]
  df <- df[!grepl("chrY", df$chr), ]
  write.csv(df, file = paste0(names(mylist)[i], ".csv"), row.names=FALSE)

}

for (i in seq(length(mylist))) {sortIt(i)}
```

If you were trying to create a new object in your workspace, then one of the `apply` functions would be a better bet. But when you're trying to output files, I think you need to use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: This gives me the error:  Error in data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE, check.rows = FALSE) : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length

Comment: Okay. Like I said, impossible to debug if you don't post a reproducible example.

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Thanks. What are you trying to do with the line `df1$X. <- NULL` in `sortIt`? And with `names(df1)[1] <- c("chr")`?

Comment: Just trying to get rid of column called X. and rename the first column to chr as some of the dataframes need this to be done

Comment: Okay, I was confused because in the sample data you posted, there is no `X.` column, and the first column is named "chr".

Comment: When I run my code on `mylist <- list(A = df, B = df)` where `df` is the sample data you posted, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but guessing that you want to save the transformed data frame to a file with a name taken from the list, this could do the job (it should work with the rest of your code - note the `[[1]]`):

```
lapply(names(mylist),
       function(x) write.csv(sortIt(mylist[x][[1]]),
                             file = paste0(x,'.csv')))
```

Another option is to use `mapply`, here I'm attaching a complete example:

```
# create the data
dframes <- lapply(1:3, function(x) data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=runif(10)))
names(dframes) <- LETTERS[1:3]

# the transformation function
sortdf <- function(df) df[order(df$x),]

# two variants of apply
lapply(names(dframes), 
       function(name) write.csv(sortdf(dframes[name][[1]]),
                                file=paste0(name, '.csv')))

# mapply does not have the ugly [[1]] syntax bit, I'd prefer it myself
mapply(function(name, df) write.csv(sortdf(df), file=paste0(name, '.csv')), 
       names(dframes),
       dframes)
```

Comment: And should the function be sortIt <- function(mylist) {        or sortIt <- function(df1) {

Comment: `sortIt <- function(df1)` - you're sorting one data frame a time. Compared to @ulfelder's answer, this is more 'functional programming' approach, you're not referencing globals from your transformation function, nor does it have any side effects like saving files to disk. I prefer (and recommend) this style.

Comment: OK so then should function(x) be function(df) and mylist[x] be mylist[df] in your answer?

Comment: OK so then should function(x) be function(df1) and mylist[x] be mylist[df1] in your answer? Also given all the dataframes are in mylist, how does the function know where df1 comes from? Would you mind ammending the whole answer so I can see how it all hooks together

Comment: @SebastianZeki Check my answer now - `x` is still `x` in `function(x)` - the name of the argument is valid only in the definition of the lambda.